# Str() in pycharm console give me object, but not string

Tags: python, string

I read the book "Hardcore Programming for Mechanical Engineer" and I stuck on a problem.

Book give us example:

```
from geom2d.affine_transforms import make_rotation
from geom2d.point import Point
import math
point = Point(15, 15)
rot_origin = make_rotation(math.pi / 4)
str(rot_origin.apply_to_point(point))
'(1.7763568394002505e-15, 21.213203435596427)'
```

I'm typing this in python console of the pycharm and instead of coordinations console shows me this:

```
str(rot_origin.apply_to_point(point))
'<geom2d.point.Point object at 0x0000023B583EB550>'
```

What I'm doing wrong, help please.

For sourse: page 191 Affine Transformation, Hardcore Programming for Mechanical Engineer by Ángel Sola Orbaiceta

Comment: both of these outputs are `str` objects. I don't know why the book shows one output, maybe the `geom2d.point.Point.__str__` changed implementations from when the book was written.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using but this probably means that what you really want to print is some some attribute of rot_origin.apply_to_point(). Do you know what that method is supposed to return? Is it an object?

Comment: It seems that the `geom2d.point.Point` class has not defined a `__str__()` or `__repr__()` method.

Comment: try to list it `list(rot_origin.apply_to_point(point))` instead of wrapping into `str()`

Comment: This looks like the Point class doesn't have a method to automatically display the object as a string.  As a guess, the point contains an x and y component. If that is true then maybe `str(rot_origin.apply_to_point(point).x)` and `str(rot_origin.apply_to_point(point).y)` will display the required data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Yes, you are right. I skipped this "unimportant" part in my code. 
Now I'm feel myself silly.

Thank you everyone for answers. I guess we can close this question.